# Asynchronously wait for process finish in elisp?

Tags: emacs, asynchronous, elisp

I would like to be able to asynchronously wait for process for example:

```el
(start-file-process "my-process" "*my-process*" "do" "something")
(on-finish "my-process"
    (do-something-else))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to read about Process Sentinels:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Sentinels` <kbd>RET</kbd>